# DirectAccess clients cannot browse network shares but can access them via mapped drive

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1, direct-access

OK, this is my first Microsoft DirectAccess deployment, so maybe I'm just lost in translation.

*I have Windows 8.1 clients connecting to a 2012 R2 multisite DirectAccess setup (2 DA servers for global load balancing).*

Once the clients are setup and working for the most part all is good.  They can access internal resources for the most part, and client Powershell diag cmdlets for DirectAccess come back with expected good results and I can ping internal resources and get the proper IPv6 response as required.

The odd part starts when we browse CIFS server shares.

I can pull up a server via UNC path, such as \EXAMPLENAS and see the shares.  However when I click on any of the shares (let's say IT) I get an error "the request is not supported" as shown below:

(sorry for the obscurity, but you get the idea)
[image]

But oddly enough, if I map a drive to that same share, say Z: to \EXAMPLENAS\IT then it immediately maps and opens the Explorer window to the share while still on DirectAccess only.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is that something by design?  If so that's frustratingly odd.
2. If it isn't by design, is there a fix for this issue?

I've checked all through the DA server setup/config and there really isn't anything that I can find that even hints at something like this, and so far every search on MS KB, Google, SF, and others seem to have been fruitless.

Comment: This isn't by design, I'm certain of that.

Comment: Thanks @mfinni - I might just open a ticket with MS Premier and be done with it, but wanted to give the community a chance to chime in.

Comment: As you know, I'm a big fan of Message Analyzer and the Performance Analyzer. Just for giggles, run one of those on a client as it connects to DA (you can configure PA to start on next boot) and tries to access a UNC. Might find something.

Comment: Are the CIFS shares on Windows servers, or a NetApp or other filer?

Comment: An EMC NAS/SAN acting as a CIFS head.  Interestingly enough, I just browsed a Windows server and CAN browse into its shares.

Comment: I wonder if that's relevant. I'm not familiar enough with those bad boys to know though. Is all IPv6 contained in the translation layer of the DA servers, or are you doing native IPv6 on the inside?

Comment: No internal IPv6, just through the NAT64 translation on the DAs.

Comment: Hmmm - that's a thread to start pulling; Message Analyzer while hitting a Windows UNC vs the NAS CIFS ought to be illuminating.